# Python: extract certain values by using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

HTML:

```
<div class="col-7"> 
    <dl class="row box">
        <h2>GENERAL</h2>
        <dt class="col-6">transmission:</dt>
        <dd class="col-6">sequential automatic</dd>
        <dt class="col-6 grey">number of seats:</dt>
        <dd class="col-6">5</dd>
        <dt class="col-6">first year of production:</dt>
        <dd class="col-6">2017</dd>
        <dt class="col-6 grey">last year of production:</dt>
        <dd class="col-6">available</dd>
    </dl>
        <dl class="row box">
        <h2>DRIVE</h2>
        <dt class="col-6">fuel:</dt>
        <dd class="col-6">petrol</dd>
        <dt class="col-6 grey">total maximum power:</dt>
        <dd class="col-6">147 kW (200 hp)</dd>
        <dt class="col-6">total maximum torque:</dt>
        <dd class="col-6">330 Nm</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="row box">
        <h2>TRANSMISSION</h2>
        <dt class="col-6">1st gear:</dt>
        <dd class="col-6">5,00:1</dd>
        <dt class="col-6 grey">2nd gear:</dt>
        <dd class="col-6">3,20:1</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

My code:

```
for item2 in soup2.find_all(attrs={'class':'col-7'}):
    jj=item2.text
```

jj can extract all the value from the website that I scraped, but I only need a few values from it. For example, I only need to extract the value of number of seats and last year of production from GENERAL and the value of 1st gear from TRANSMISSION.

The result should be:

```
5, available, 5,00:1
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to actually solve the problem at hand? Your code doesn't seem particularly related.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's related, I already did other parts, and this is the last part I need to solve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The information you need is simply the next item of the titles "number of seats", "last year of production", and "1st gear", so you can loop through the item and next item by using `zip`

```
all_items = soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'col-6'})
titles = [
    "number of seats", 
    "last year of production", 
    "1st gear"
]
d = {title: [] for title in titles}

for item, next_item in zip(all_items, all_items[1:]):
    for title in titles:
        if title in item.text:
            d[title].append(next_item.text)
            break
```

Then `d` will contain all the information you need

Answer (score 0):

Change the find_values tuple to get values from html text

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    find_values = ('number of seats', 'last year of production', '1st gear') 
    for i in soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'row box'}):
       for j in i.find_all('dt'):
           text = j.get_text().lower().strip()
           if text.startswith(find_values):
               print(text, j.find_next_sibling('dd').get_text())
```